# How in Android do I centre text that changes per second?

Tags: java, android

I've got some Android code that works fine to make a piece of text count down...

```
final TextView mTextField = new TextView(this);

            mTextField.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            mTextField.setTextSize(25);
            mTextField.setTypeface(tf);
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    mTextField.setText("Days : " + getTimes()[0] + " Hours : "
                            + getTimes()[1] + " Minutes : " + getTimes()[2]
                            + " Seconds : " + getTimes()[3]);

                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

                }
            };

            handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
            setContentView(mTextField);
```

The problem I have is, I can't format this text in anyway, I want it to be like exact centre of the screen, but as the text is actually in Java rather than XML, how would I go about say embedding this inside a relativeLayout so I can control the location of where the text is printed to the screen?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a parent that is a FrameLayout and set gravity for center and then add that TextView:

```
FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,Gravity.CENTRAL)
frame.setLayoutParams(params);


 final TextView mTextField = new TextView(this);

 mTextField.setTextColor(Color.RED);
 mTextField.setTextSize(25);
 mTextField.setTypeface(tf);
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
      final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               mTextField.setText("Days : " + getTimes()[0] + " Hours : "
                        + getTimes()[1] + " Minutes : " + getTimes()[2]
                        + " Seconds : " + getTimes()[3]);

                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

frame.addView(mTextField);
setContentView(frame);
```

**UPDATE 1**: Fixed the FrameLayout.LayoutParams.

Comment: I get "FILL_PARENT" is not a field and "CENTRAL_VERTICAL" is not a field, I'm using Android 2.1.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to center your text programatically. here is a method, use `setGravity()` , see this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3agravity) for argument options..